# Calculate time between two dates in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hoping this is fairly elementary. I have a Spark dataframe containing a Date column, I want to add a new column with number of days since that date. Google fu is failing me.

Here's what I've tried:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

schema = StructType([StructField("foo", DateType(), True)])
l = [(datetime.date(2016,12,1),)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, schema)
df = df.withColumn('daysBetween',today - df.foo)
df.show()
```

it fails with error:

> u"cannot resolve '(17212 - foo)' due to data type mismatch: '(17212 -
>   foo)' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not date;"

I've tried fiddling around but gotten nowhere. I can't think that this is too hard. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, figured it out

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as funcs
import datetime
today = datetime.date(2017,2,15)

schema = StructType([StructField("foo", DateType(), True)])
l = [(datetime.date(2017,2,14),)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, schema)
df = df.withColumn('daysBetween',funcs.datediff(funcs.lit(today), df.foo))
df.collect()
```

returns `[Row(foo=datetime.date(2017, 2, 14), daysBetween=1)]`

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('daysSince', F.datediff(F.current_date(), df.foo))
```

Comment: So others can know: the differences are in days https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.datediff